# Normalize data by first value in the group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a DataFrame of 6 million rows of intraday data that looks like such:

```
                          closingDate      Time    Last 
1997-09-09 11:30:00-04:00  1997-09-09  11:30:00    100
1997-09-09 11:31:00-04:00  1997-09-09  11:31:00    105
```

I want to normalize my `Last` column in a vectorized manner by dividing every row by the price on the first row that contains that day. This is my attempt:

```
df['Last']/df.groupby('closingDate').first()['Last']
```

The denominator looks like such:

```
closingDate
1997-09-09     943.25
1997-09-10     942.50
1997-09-11     928.00
1997-09-12     915.75
1997-09-14     933.00
1997-09-15     933.00
```

However, this division just gives me a column of nans. How can I associate the division to be broadcasted across my DateTime index?

Comment: divide using `df.groupby('closingDate').first()['Last'].values`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, this is a good use case for `transform`:

```
df['Last'] /= df.groupby('closingDate')['Last'].transform('first')
```

The groupby result is broadcasted with respect to the original DataFrame, and division is now made possible.